# Windows 7 icon highlighting

Tags: windows-7, icons, highlighting

When I select an icon, the text and the icon get highlighted but in some folders (the D: drive for example), it highlights the space around the icon as well and that annoys me.

How can I disable the squares around the selected icons and make it only highlight the text and the icon like in Windows XP?

[image: Icons highlighted]

I can't remember how I disabled it before, it was 2 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have different folder view set for those folders. Click the little black arrow under the search box and choose Icons view.

If it doesn't change help, try to view folder's properties and on the *Customize* tab change *Optimize this folder for* to *General items*.

Comment: It is the same for all folders. I have tried changing it but it didn't affect the highlighting.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: I have tried all of the types and none worked. :(

Comment: Have you tried it on D: or on D:\Files?

Comment: On both. When I enter any subfolder, it starts working normally. Only the root of D: has different highlighting.